# How would I go about saving a users latitude and longitude in my postgres table for a user using the html5 map?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, maps

So what we're trying to do is once the user clicks that he/she wants their position to be saved we'll save it to our longitude and latitude columns. Thanks for help and looking over for us!

https://github.com/rolaandoes/nexu/tree/dev

Our html file where the button is to save our user location (latitude, longitude)

```
 <h1>Users#edit for <%= @user.id %></h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/users/edit.html.erb</p>
    <p><button onclick="geoFindMe()" data-id="<%= @user.id %>"id="finder-    btn">Geo-Coordnate My Position</button>Send Coordinates to DB</p>
<div id="out"></div>
    <h2>Coordinates to DataBase!</br>lat, lon</h2>
    <a href="#" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='#990000'">Paint it red</a>
```

This is our js file

```
$(function(){

  $('#finder-btn').on('click', function (){

    var currentUserId = $(this).attr('data-id')

    $.ajax({
      url: '/users/' + currentUserId,
      data: { latitude: LatLng[0], longitude: LatLng[1] },
      type: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Patch Succesful!")
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log("Error Thrown")
      }
    });
  });
});


//update location for current_user

        LatLng = [];
        console.log(LatLng);

       var latitude = LatLng[0]
       var longitude = LatLng[1]



function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;


    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    // console.log(longitude);
    // console.log(latitude);
    //PLUCK into Location TABLE

    // latitude = lat_Jon;
    // longitude = lon_Jon;

    LatLng.push(latitude);
    LatLng.push(longitude);


    output.appendChild(img);
  };

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  };

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Our users_controller that we need to update the location on our table for latitude and longitude

```
def update
    # @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    user_id = current_user.id
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)

    puts @user.latitude
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are going on here that might be giving you trouble.

1. You are doing a `GET` instead of a `POST` or `PUT` to try and update the user's latitude and longitude.

   Try changing your AJAX call from `type: 'get'` to `type: 'post'` this will help Rails determine which controller action to route your request to (the one you want is `users_controller#update`
2. In your `users_controller`, use `params[:id]` to find the user, the code would look like:

   `user = User.find(params[:user_id])`
3. In the same way you found the user, you need to parse the lat and lon out of params. Your `user_params` method is making assumptions about the parameters that you're not actually enforcing. It things you have data that looks like:

   `{ 'user': { 'longitude': '29.388', 'latitude': '187.39848' } }`

   however your params look like:

   `{ 'longitude': '29.388', 'latitude': '182.3888' }`

   So you need to do the same thing as above, use `params[:longitude]` and `params[:latitude]`

   I would write it like:

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def update
       user = User.find(params[:id])
       user.update!(latitude: params[:latitude], longitude: params[:longitude])
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks yez! We got it! Our instructor came in and helped my team mates out. I initially wanted to work through this from the controller. But it looks like they got it up and running! I hugely appreciate your answer! Here's what we have so far in case you want to see how we're doing - https://github.com/rolaandoes/nexu/tree/master